# Listener to Tab Item Click in Sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, listener, tabpanel

In my application, I'm using a tab panel with 5 items in it. Each item holds around 6 panels added in card layout. When I'm at the last panel inside a tab item, I need to get back to the initial panel by clicking on the bottom tab panel (somewhat similar to a normal tab view controller in iOS). I have came across [some solutions I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519731/how-to-call-a-function-on-a-controller-when-tapping-on-tabpanel-sencha-touch-2), but it seems to work only when I switch between the tabs. In fact I want to listen to the click event on the same tab icon. How can I do this?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519731/how-to-call-a-function-on-a-controller-when-tapping-on-tabpanel-sencha-touch-2). Nearby same solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have worked on your problem. I think this is exactly what you want. Hope this helps. If not so, please leave a comment.

1). **View (MyTabPanel1.js)**

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTabPanel1', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    config: {

            scrollable: 'vertical',
             items:
            [
                {
                   xtype: 'panel',
                   id:'cardpanel1',
                   title: 'Tab1',              
                   layout: 'card',
                        items: [
                            {  
                                html: "First Item",
                                items:
                                [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    text: 'Forward',
                                    handler: function() {
                                    Ext.getCmp('cardpanel1').setActiveItem(1);
                                    console.log('Going to Second Item');
                                    }
                                }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                html: "Second Item",
                                items:
                                [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    ui: 'confirm',
                                    text: 'Go back',
                                    handler: function() {
                                    Ext.getCmp('cardpanel1').setActiveItem(0);
                                    console.log('Going to First Item');
                                    }
                                }
                                ]
                            }

                        ]               

                },

                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Tab2',
                    scrollable: true,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            margin: 10,
                            ui: 'action',
                            text: 'Tab2'
                        }

                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Tab3',
                    scrollable: true,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            margin: 10,
                            ui: 'action',
                            text: 'Tab3'
                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        }

    });
```

2). **Controller (MainController.js)**

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MainController', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
        config: {
            control: {

                "tabpanel #ext-tab-1":{  //ext-tab-1 is the id for the 1st tab generated by Sencha
                   tap: 'ontap'
                }            
            }
        },

        ontap: function (){
        console.log('inside controller');
        Ext.getCmp('cardpanel1').setActiveItem(0);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would give a much simpler solution

This is my view called Viewport which is a TabPanel:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.iphone.Viewport',{
           extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
           xtype: 'newviewport',
           alias: 'widget.newTabPanel',
```

Now in my controller file:

```
    Ext.define('Sencha.controller.iphone.main', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
        config:
        {
        refs: {
        theMainTabPanelTabbarTab: 'newTabPanel > tabbar > tab', //this the tab of the tabpanel, if we listen to it that way we will know of tab panel tap.
        },
        control: {
        theMainTabPanelTabbarTab:{
        tap: 'onTapMainTabPanel'
        }
}
```

This is a working code and works fine. Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Good one. Only change I would suggest is to use delegate in the view and then fireEvent to controller rather than making this much of deep nesting in the controller